# Why Shiny app does not work when app.R from another app is saved in a new one?

Tags: r, shiny

I have noticed that whenever I want to create a new shiny app I have to create a new app.R file in the new app folder. If I 'save as' the app.R from another shiny app in the new folder and modify it for the current usage, the UI is created but server doesn't seem to work. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at what happens when you press the "Run App" button -- the command that gets executed in the console is `shiny::runApp(appDir)`. It doesn't run specifically the `app.R` file, but it runs the whole directory. This is the first hint at why you're seeing this behaviour - Shiny expects to run an app as a directory rather than as a file, so when you have a different app file in the same folder, the original one is probably still getting run.

This lead me to look into the `runApp` function. If you look at the documentation for `runApp` you'll see the first parameter is `appDir`:

> The directory of the application. Should contain server.R, plus,
>   either ui.R or a www directory that contains the file index.html.
>   Alternately, instead of server.R and ui.R, the directory may contain
>   just app.R. Defaults to the working directory. Instead of a directory,
>   this could be a list with ui and server components, or a Shiny app
>   object created by shinyApp.

So there you have it - `runApp` (and therefore the "Run App" button) uses a directory as the parameter for the Shiny app. Shiny expects this directory to either have `server.R` and `ui.R` OR  just `app.R`, but it doesn't say what the behaviour is when you have a combination of that or more than one `app` or non of the above, so you should avoid that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.